# IntelliJ 13.1.4 indexing every build

Tags: java, maven-2, intellij-13

Every time I build my project with maven through IntelliJ, IntelliJ begins to index.

Is there any way to prevent IntelliJ from indexing?

Comment: Reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project tool window right-click on the build/artifact directory and click on "mark directory > as excluded".